# Counters and numbering new environments

Tags: numbering, counters

I need two new environments for a Proposition and a Lemma in the appendix. But the first problem is that the numbering of the Proposition does not follow the numbering of the Lemma, and the second problem is that even though I have `\newcounter{lemmaa}[section]` and the section is the appendix, this doesn't put an A in front of the number of the lemma. So I have put it manually as you can see in the definition of the environments.

```
\newcounter{lemmaa}[section]

\newcounter{propa}[lemmaa]

\newenvironment{lemmaa}[1][]{\refstepcounter{lemmaa}\par\vspace{0.5cm}

    \noindent \textbf{\normalsize Lemma~A.\thelemmaa.} #1\\[0.2cm]

    \noindent \itshape }{\medskip}

\newenvironment{propa}[1][]{\refstepcounter{propa}\par\vspace{0.5cm}

    \noindent \textbf{\normalsize Proposition~A.\thepropa.} #1\\[0.2cm]

    \noindent \itshape}{\medskip}
```

Comment: By "follow", do you mean that they are sequential? If that, then just use `\thelemmaa` inside the `propa` environment; there's no need for an additional counter then.

Comment: Why aren't you using `\newtheorem`?

Comment: As egreg mentions why are you doing this by hand when `\newtheorem` does this for you,

Comment: Thank you Werner !! Ok yes, you have to remove the newcounter and also replace propa with lemmaa in the \refstepcounter as well! This solved one of the problems!! :)

Comment: Any idea how to make the numbering begin automathically with A? And not \textbf{\normalsize Lemma~A.\thelemmaa.} ? This is important as I have to change the references everywhere where use \ref{label}

Comment: To egreg and daleif: because I want different formatting of the environment: particularly space between the title and the body, is there  a way to modify this with \newtheorem ?

Comment: I can do ```\textbf{\normalsize Lemma~\thesection.\thelemmaa.}``` but this doesn't change the problem when I have to use```\ref{label}```. I guess I need to modify the ```\refstepcounter{}```, but I don't understand how.

Comment: See `thmtools` for example. If you are a novice it is never a good idea to to things like this.